# How to fix the overflow of contents in webpage when zooming in?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

the left floated object keeps overlapping with right floated object.

css for left floated:

```
.righthomebar {
  background-color: brown;
  height:920px;
  position:absolute;
  top:60px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float:left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

css for right floated div:

```
.content-text {
  min-height:550px;
  max-width: 850px;
  border-style:solid;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  top: 20px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: insert your html pls. without your html it will be difficult to help

Comment: Without the HTML snippet, it is hard to help you. Anyway, you should use a `media query` to fix this issue.

Comment: sorry for the hasssel guys...i am just focusing and moving on with single web development course  which hasnt gotten me into responsive designing part yet so im trying to figure out as long as it just works on my desktop screen size, its fine for now... but just wanted to  check if i could fix the displacement issues while zooming in without really diving in the responsive design part.

Comment: haha it doesnt let me post  all my html or i might have not known how to include all my code.

Answer (score 0):

Scale your elements using these units:

```
vw - Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport
vh - Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport
vmin - Relative to 1% of viewport's smaller dimension
vmax - Relative to 1% of viewport's larger dimension
```

Comment: Thank you so much but i havent moved yet to viewport or flexbox. just tried floating divs inside the container then when i zoom out its fine i could make the width and everything stay intact but just while zooming in i want that constant view just zoomed in as if it was a picture without moving the content at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) on parent

css part:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: between; /* See more property in MDN*/
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Move right part to new line when overlapping */
  width: 300px;
}
```

html part:

```
<div class=“parent”>
  <div>Left part</div>
  <div>Right part</div>
</div>
```

`justify-content` property [detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: Thank you so much but i havent moved yet to viewport or flexbox. just tried floating divs inside the container then when i zoom out its fine i could make the width and everything stay intact but just while zooming in i want that constant view just zoomed in as if it was a picture without moving the content at all.